# How to extends fragment with image in Android? which is the image come from a website

Tags: java, android, fragment

I want to extends my fragment with an image, which is the image come from a website. So this is my code:

public class tab1 extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,container,false);
    ImageView iklansatu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iklanpertama);

    String gambar1="https://www.nomindphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Gentle-View-20141125-_DSC7035.jpg";

    try {
        URL newurl = new URL(gambar1);
        Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
        iklansatu.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return view;
}
```

}

So, whats wrong with my code? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you have added internet permission in manifest.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,container,false);
    ImageView iklansatu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iklanpertama);

        try {
            URL newurl = new URL(gambar1[0]);
            Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
            iklansatu.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
           } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    return  view;
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve the symbol "mIcon_val" and
"new URL(gambar1[0]);" has a red underline. 
So i cant compile your modified code.

Comment: still have an error in "(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());", it has red color and say "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: I edit the code, so my code same with your code. The code is succes to build but when i try the apps, but my apps doesnt appear the image. How to fix it?

Comment: Paste url value here

Comment: https://www.nomindphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Gentle-View-20141125-_DSC7035.jpg thats the url value

Comment: do you have team viwer?\